# Table View Cell not displaying when Running iOS Simulator

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I'm trying to create a table but none of the data I inputted is displaying when I run the simulator. I'm trying to create a simple address book application and So far, here is what I did:

1. From the empty story board, I added a View Controller from the Object Library then inside the view controller, I added a Table View. Then I embedded the View Controller inside a Navigation Controller. I also added another View Controller in the end to act as a "Details" View.
   [image]
2. Inside my viewController.h I added the following code:

   ```
   @property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *contact;
   @property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *contactDetails;
   @property (nonatomic) NSInteger selectedIndex;
   ```

contact is to act as the array that shows all the contacts within the phonebook (This is what I'm having trouble displaying)

contactDetails shows once a user selects a contact.

selectedIndex is my way of telling the application which contact has been selected.

3. Inside my viewController.m I added the following code:

   ```
   #import "HWViewController.h"

   @interface HWViewController ()

   @end

   @implementation HWViewController

   - (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
   {
        self = [super initWithStyle:style];
             if (self) {
                 // Custom initialization
             }
        return self;
   }

   - (void)viewDidLoad
   {
       [super viewDidLoad];
       // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

       [self.tableView registerClass: [UITableViewCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];

       self.contact = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray: [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Joe", @"Simon", nil]];

       self.contactDetails = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray: [NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"+689171898057", @"+689173104153", nil]];

   }

   - (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
   {
       [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
       // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
   }

   - (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
   {
       // Return the number of sections.
       return 1;
   } 

   - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
   {
       // Return the number of rows in the section.
       return self.contact.count;
   }

   - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
   {

       static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
       UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

       // Configure the cell...

       if(cell==nil){

           cell = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"SampleCell" owner:nil options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];

       }

       UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 100, 30)];
       label.text = [self.contact objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
       [cell.contentView addSubview:label];

       return cell;
   } 

   -(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
       //UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
       self.selectedIndex = indexPath.row;
       [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"TranslationSegue" sender:self];
   }

   - (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
   {
       // Get the new view controller using [segue destinationViewController].
       // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
       UIViewController *vc = [segue destinationViewController];
       UILabel *details = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 80, 250, 32)];
       details.text = [self.contactDetails objectAtIndex:((HWViewController*)sender).selectedIndex];
       [vc.view addSubview:details];
   }


   @end
   ```

After that, I ran the simulation and I get nothing showing up on the table.

Comment: Have you set your class as the delegate and the data source for the Tableview in IB?

Answer (score 0):

you have no cell in the tableview. so add tableview cell in your storyboard

http://www.appcoda.com/customize-table-view-cells-for-uitableview/

[image]

Comment: I did just that and also added Reuse Identifiers that worked along with my .m file but still the result was an empty set.

Answer (score 0):

Add this in your viewController.h :

```
@property(nonatomic, strong) IBOUTLET UITableView * TableView;
```

And then link this outlet to your tableview and then try it out.

And there is no cell in your table view because the prototype cell will be set to **zero** by default. Now select the tableview go to attribute inspector and set the prototype cell to 1 and then try to run your program with proper **cell identifier** it will work.

HTH :)

Comment: I added the table view cell and I also added the Reuse Identifiers but still no sign of any table population.

Comment: did u include - @property(nonatomic, strong) IBOUTLET UITableView * TableView;
and link this IBOutlet to your tableview??

Answer (score 0):

Set tableView delegate and DataSource protocol in you viewdidload method.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
     {
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

[self.tableView registerClass: [UITableViewCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];

 self.tableview.delegate = self;
 self.tableview.dataSource = self;

self.contact = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray: [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Joe", @"Simon", nil]];

self.contactDetails = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray: [NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"+689171898057", @"+689173104153", nil]];

}
```

Comment: I added the delegates and it did not fix my problem. I still have an unpopulated table.

Comment: You need to do some more debugging. If your delegate and datasource are properly working then check numberofRowInSection method. Use NSLog to check number of rows you are getting. If this method is not calling then there is some problem in setting the protocals.